# Amazon mobile in app purchase. proper initialization

Tags: android, flash, in-app-purchase, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am implementing in app purchases for Android. And in documentation they write:

1. registerObserver() needs to be called within your Start() method.
2. initiateGetUserIdRequest() needs to be called within your Start() method.
3. initiatePurchaseUpdatesREquest() should be called whithin the onStart() method.
4. initiateDataRequest() can be called
5. initiatePurchaseRequest() can be called.

So the question really is:   do I really need to call initiateGetUserIdRequest() wright after registerObserver ??? Is it critically?? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you only must call it if you need the userId.**

They still are working on the documentation. Even that, I think you have an older version of it, if you go to the developer portal I think you'll find a new version that it's still not definitive.